# Difference between "made" and "had made"?

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect

As a non-native English speaker, I'm a little bit confused. Should I say:

> when we were children we made our own toys

OR

> when we were children we had made our own toys

What is the difference between the two sentences ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should say:

> When we were children, we made our own toys.

Past perfect tense is used to indicate that one event happened before another event in the past. But because the two events 'being children' and 'making toys' happened at the same time, you can't use past perfect tense in this instance. You can't say that 'when we were children we had made our own toys' because you would be using past perfect tense incorrectly.

The difference between the two sentences is that

> When we **were** children, we **made** our own toys

makes use of the simple past tense and is grammatically correct while

> When we **were** children we **had made** our own toys

makes use of past perfect tense and is grammatically incorrect.